# how can I get final embeddings from word2vec.py?

Tags: tensorflow, word2vec

I am using word2vec.py from Google, see the link below:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.7/tensorflow/models/embedding/word2vec.py

I want to extract the final embeddings of words and save it to a txt file. How can I find the final embeddings?

Comment: @tanjir word2vec is to represent words by vectors in some embedding space. The embedding vectors are learned/updated through some neural network. In word2vec.py, they test the results by some analogy questions. Now, I want to extract the final embedding vectors for all words in corpus.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out how to do it.

I created a self._nemb_final in build_eval_graph model to transfer the nemb out.
After the model is trained, we can then do sth. like below:

```
final_embedding = self._nemb_final.eval()     
np.savetxt('/.../final_embedding_dic.txt',final_embedding)
```

Comment: that just saves the vectors what about the vocabulary ?

Comment: @Michelle Owen :  how to get the vectors with vocabulory?

Comment: @ThomasNT  you can simply join the vocabulary with the embedding vectors together.

Comment: @trailblazer see above please